# How to get records before the specified dates in powerapps

Tags: date, powerapps

I am trying to create a calculation model using Microsoft Powerapps Powerfx query.

I want to condition and get records if their date is less than or equal to the specified date.
How can this be achieved in the Powerfx query.
Condition is get all records on or before 11/1/2021.(Refer following image)

[image: error]

Please let me know how can this be achieved.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you try `Activity.msdyn_consumptionstartdate <= Date(2021, 11, 1)`? The value `11/1/2021` is not a date, but a pair of divisions (11/1, then the result divided by 2021).

Comment: From the screenshot, it doesn't look like the error is with `11/1/2021` but with `msdyn_consumptionstartdate` - does this column exist and is it a date datatype?

Comment: Yes, the column does exist.

Comment: @carlosfigueira, the solution that you've specified did work for me today, I tried it earlier but it didn't work for some reason. Glad it worked after all. Thank you!